# I am not able to load more pages using Endless RecyclerView ScrollListener

Tags: android

I am using Recyclerview to achieve endless recyclerview scroll listener. Now it loading only page = 1 and page = 2 while scrolling but it not loading another pages, and I added **EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener** class from github.

**Activity**

```
public class AccountPagination extends AppCompatActivity implements RestCallback {
String UserId, rollname, username, name, fname, lname, emailid, contact_no, gender1, date_of_birth, country_id, postal_code, profession_response, Street_Address, City;
NonScrollListView listItem;
public static AccountStatementAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<AccountStatementModel> AccountStatementList;
AccountsSortingAdapter adapterSort;
AccountsTenRecordsAdapter adapterTenRecords;
ArrayList<AccountStatementModel> AccountDetailsList;
ArrayList<AccountStatementModel> AccountSortingList;
ArrayList<AccountStatementModel> AccountTenRecordsList;

ArrayList<AccountStatementModel> androidVersions;
List<AccountStatementModel> AccountList;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
int userPage = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account_pagination);
    initViews();

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.card_recycler_view);
    callAccountStatementAPI(userPage);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
  //  recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
            userPage++;
            callAccountStatementAPI(userPage);
        }
    });

    //RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    //RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 1);


}

public void initViews() {
    Intent i = getIntent();
    UserId = i.getStringExtra("id");
    name = SharedPref.read(SharedPref.FIRST_NAME, "") + "\t" + SharedPref.read(SharedPref.LAST_NAME, "");
    String Hello = "Hello " + name;
    getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(Hello);
}

private void callAccountStatementAPI(final int page) {

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("user_id", SharedPref.read(SharedPref.USER_ID, ""));
    map.put("page", String.valueOf(page));
    RestService.getInstance(AccountPagination.this).getAccount1(map, new MyCallback<ArrayList<AccountStatementModel>>(AccountPagination.this,
            AccountPagination.this, true, "Loading ...", GlobalVariables.SERVICE_MODE.ACCOUNT_STATEMENT));

}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t, GlobalVariables.SERVICE_MODE mode) {

}

@Override
public void onSuccess(Response response, GlobalVariables.SERVICE_MODE mode) {
    switch (mode) {
        case ACCOUNT_STATEMENT:

            androidVersions = (ArrayList<AccountStatementModel>) response.body();
            AccountPaginationAdapter adapter = new AccountPaginationAdapter(getApplicationContext(), androidVersions);
            androidVersions.addAll((Collection<? extends AccountStatementModel>) response.body());
            adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(adapter.getItemCount(), androidVersions.size()-2);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            break;
    }
}
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
    public class AccountPaginationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AccountPaginationAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<AccountStatementModel> android_versions;
private Context context;

private String TAG = "On Click";
String main_url = "http://www.consumer1st.in/ccb/";

public AccountPaginationAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AccountStatementModel> android_versions) {
    this.context = context;
    this.android_versions = android_versions;

}

@Override
public AccountPaginationAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.accountpagination_item_list, viewGroup, false);
    return new AccountPaginationAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AccountPaginationAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {


    viewHolder.lable_name.setText(android_versions.get(position).getRemarks());


    viewHolder.icon_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String icoon_index_id = android_versions.get(position).getId();
            String iconn_id = android_versions.get(position).getUserId();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return android_versions.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView lable_name;

    ImageView icon_image;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        icon_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
        lable_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lable_name);
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: That's not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Below the code will work But this code totally wrong way actually u are calling every api hit to creating new adapter and adding list. See more pagination examples and change it..  [See reference here](https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-pagination-tutorial-getting-started-recyclerview/).

Write a method in Adapter Class:

```
    public void addMoreItems(ArrayList<AccountStatementModel> newItems){
       androidVersions.addAll(newItems);
    }
```

Write Activity:

```
case ACCOUNT_STATEMENT:

androidVersions = (ArrayList<AccountStatementModel>) response.body();
AccountPaginationAdapter adapter = new AccountPaginationAdapter(getApplicationContext(), androidVersions);
androidVersions.addAll((Collection<? extends AccountStatementModel>) response.body());
adapter.addMoreItems(androidVersions);
adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(adapter.getItemCount(), androidVersions.size()-2);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
break;
}
```

Comment: He dude this is totally wrong. Refer that link and change your code ... Don't do like this...

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this you will get perfect result.

     int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

           recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new
           RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                               if (dy > 0) {
                                   visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
                                   totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                                   pastVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                                   if (loading && totalItemCount >= (pastVisiblesItems + 50)) {
                                       userPage++;
                callAccountStatementAPI(userPage);
                                       Log.v("...", "Last Item Wow !");
                                       //Do pagination.. i.e. fetch new data
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                       });
```